# Form data with image file not posting to url angular

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to send form data to php url, but it is not posting. it is working fine with HTML code. but not working in angular

Angular code:

```
   const payload = new FormData();
   payload.append('name', this.author);
   payload.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

   this.http
     .post(`request-url`,
     payload,
      {
          headers : {
              'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
          }
      }
    ).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.resData = data;
      console.log(this.resData);
    });
```

HTML working code

```
<form method="POST" action="request-url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        id="textauthor"
        name="name" 
        placeholder="Name"></input>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on just HTML to send that request, then it will go without an issue. But since you want it to go via your component code, you'll have to bind to the `ngSubmit` event of the `form`. This will call a function in your TypeScript class. In this eg. it is `onSubmit`.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="image">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="textauthor" name="name" placeholder="Name"></input>
    <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here's Typescript:

```
onSubmit() {
  const payload = new FormData();
  payload.append('name', this.author);
  payload.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

  this.http
    .post(`request-url`,
      payload, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
    ).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.resData = data;
      console.log(this.resData);
    });
}
```

### UPDATE:

First up, there were a few issues with your code, which I fixed in the updated stackblitz.

The API URL that you've provided is hosted on HTTP while the project is hosted on HTTPS. So the browser will block the API request by giving a Mixed-Content Error.

If I try to change it from HTTP to HTTPS then it gave me a CORS error which means that you'll have to whitelist your domain on that API to make it work.

Here's an [Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multipart-form-eg).

Comment: it is calling that method and url too. data is not going to url

Comment: Please consider creating a stackblitz.

Comment: please check this added url, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyssf6